# Secure parameter in Codeigniter PHP controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters, coinbase-api

I'm trying to create callback script for Coinbase bitcoin payments. Here is the below function from my payment controller:

```
function callback($secret = NULL) {
    if ($secret == 'testSECRETkey') {

    //If order is "completed", please proceed.

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

    $status = $data['order']['status'];
    $userid = '507';

    if (($status === 'completed')) {
        $this->db->query( 'update users set user_money=user_money+15, user_credits=user_credits+5 WHERE users_id=' . $userid );
    }
}
```

How to include `special parameter`, so when I request the url: `www.example.com/payments/callback`
to add special key and if it's not valid to reject access to the script. Example:

```
www.example.com/payments/callback?secret=testSECRETkey
```

**Unfortunately, it doesnt work as I want. It doesnt take effect. Whats wrong on it?**

Answer (score 0):

To access the `key` parameter you will use the Input class' `get` method https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

`$this->input->get('key');`

```
function callback()
{
    $key = $this->input->get('key');
    if( ! $this->is_valid_key($key)) {
       // do something here and return
       return;
    }

    //If order is "completed", please proceed.

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

    $status = $data['order']['status'];
    $userid = '507';

    if (($status === 'completed')) {
        $this->db->query( 'update users set user_money=user_money+15, user_credits=user_credits+5 WHERE users_id=' . $userid );
    }
}
```

Create a new method to validate the key

```
function is_valid_key($key) {
    // logic to check key
    $valid = true;
    if($valid) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that and I am using it like that: `http://www.example.com/payments/callback?key=true` but It doesn't work at all. I mean it's not affecting it.

Comment: what happens when you `print_r($this->input->get());`?

Comment: Make sure you have GET allowed in `application/config/config.php` - - `$config['allow_get_array']  = TRUE;`